# how can i find the location, on my HDD, of the apps listed in windows 10 data usage

Tags: windows

my question is: 
how can i find the location, on my HDD, of the apps listed in windows 10 data usage

verbose:
hi
in windows 10 data usage (start > settings > Network & Internet > Usage details) i get a list of apps i use and a number reflecting how much i have used that app (xGB or xMB or xKB). in my case, i get, on that list (along with apps with names i know), apps with no name but just long long numbers followed by an .exe extension. this makes me uncomfortable. when i click on the apps name (both known and unknown), nothing happens...

again, my question is: 
how can i find the location, on my HDD, of the apps listed in windows 10 data usage

Comment: Good question. It's frustrating that they don't show you the full path. Have you tried searching your computer for the files? Could be that they were installation files or windows updates.

Comment: yes, i have tried searching but it ran a while and i couldnt let it finish - thanks for the reminder (i'll do it again now...